# How to compute $I_{m,n,k}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sinh^n(x) \coth^{2k+n+m-1}(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, gamma-function, hyperbolic-functions

To compute $I_{m,n,k}$, expressing the integrand function with the function $\tanh$. As $\coth(x)=\frac{\cosh(x)}{\sinh(x)}$ and $\frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)}= 1 -\tanh^2(x)$, we get
\begin{align}
I_{m,n,k}&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\sinh^n(x) \coth^{2k+n+m-1}(x)} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh^{2k+m-1}(x)}{(\sinh(x)\coth(x))^{n}} dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh^{2k+m-1}(x)}{\cosh^{n}(x)} dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \tanh^{2k+m-1}(x) (1-\tanh^{2}(x))^{\frac{n}{2}}dx\\
&= ....?
\end{align}
Otherwise, as $\tanh(t)'=1 -\tanh(t)^2$, we get
\begin{align}
I_{m,n,k}&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \tanh^{2k+m-1}(x) (\tanh(x)')^{\frac{n}{2}}dx= ??
\end{align}

I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you write $$\int_0^\infty\tanh^{2k+m-1}x(1-\tanh^2x)^{\frac n2 -1}(1-\tanh^2x) dx$$
Then you do the change of variable $y=\tanh x$, and you get $$\int_0^1y^{2k+m-1}(1-y^2)^{\frac n2 -1} dy$$